# Java regex in scanner

Tags: java, regex

I know it is simple, but I do not know why it does not work.

I try to check if next String in scanner is matched by the pattern:
String should begins with

`"   DESCRIPTION"`.
So, I try:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("   DESCRIPTION = 'Header for scroller'");
System.out.println("Has Next = " + sc.hasNext("\\s+DESCRIPTION.*"));
```

but it does not work, why?
Simpler regex works fine:

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner("   DESCRIPTION = 'Заголовки таблиц скроллеров'");
 System.out.println("Has Next = " + sc.hasNext(".*DESCRIPTION.*"));
```

Answer (score 2):

`sc.hasNext(pattern)` returns `true` if the next token matches `pattern`.

The next token here is `"DESCRIPTION"`.

- `"DESCRIPTION"` *matches* `.*DESCRIPTION.*`
- `"DESCRIPTION"` *does not match* `\s+DESCRIPTION.*` (since there are no spaces before the token)

---

You could try this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("   DESCRIPTION = 'Header for scroller'");
System.out.println("Has Next = " + sc.hasNext("DESCRIPTION.*"));
```

```
Has Next = true
```

Answer (score 1):

From JavaDoc of [`Scanner#hasNext(String pattern)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28java.lang.String%29)

> Returns true **if the next token** matches the pattern constructed from
>   the specified string

So

```
sc.hasNext("\\s+DESCRIPTION.*")
```

returns false because the next token is `DESCRIPTION` (without any whitespace) and

```
sc.hasNext(".*DESCRIPTION.*")
```

returns true because both of the `.*` match 0 characters before and after `DESCRIPTION`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not what you're looking for, but

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("   DESCRIPTION = 'Header for scroller'".trim());
System.out.println("Has Next = " + sc.hasNext("^DESCRIPTION.*"));
```

did the trick for me...

Answer (score 0):

Its because the default delimiter pattern for scanner is `\p{javaWhitespace}+`

Hence the next token becomes `DESCRIPTION` rather than `<space><space>DESCRIPTION`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work for you because Scanner uses whitespace as a default delimiter. Thus hasNext cannot find \s+DESCRIPTION and finds .*DESCRIPTION.* or just DESCRIPTION.*. If you would have changed your code to

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("   DESCRIPTION = 'Header for scroller'");
sc.useDelimiter( "_" );
System.out.println("Has Next = " + sc.hasNext("\\s+DESCRIPTION.*"));
```

then you would have expected result.